# req.pipe(...) is not firing on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

this part of my '/upload' route behaves in a very strange way:

```js
    console.log("1st point");

    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {

        console.log("can never be reached");
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
    console.log("2nd point");
```

it never reaches busboy functionality and idk why.

On the localhost and Amazon Linux everything works fine, but on heroku this part of code is usually just skipped. It drives me crazy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure if this is because of the way Heroku has setup the file systems for dynos. Please refer to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem and see if it helps.

Comment: thx, i'm on it. Will see if i can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in

```js
res.redirect('/profile');
```

this function was being called (and change session before

```js
req.pipe(busboy);
```

is done. Idk why it worked on Amazon, might be something in architecture of heroky VM. The problem has been solved by adding this code:

```js
var req_stream = req.pipe(busboy);
    req_stream.on('finish', function () {
        res.redirect('/profile');
    });
```

And now it works fine on heroku.